# Interleave TFRecordDatasets of different lengths

Tags: python, tensorflow, parsing, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'd like to interleave TFRecordDatasets of different sizes after having processed them indipendently.

In other words, I need the output to be equal to the concatenatation of all parts. While parts may be shuffled, I need to preserve the order within each part. For instance, if parts are of the form `abc`, `def`, `ghi`, the ouput should be `abcdefghi` (or any combination like `abcghidef` that still preserves the internal order of each part).

I played a bit with the `cycle_length` and `block_length` options of the interleave API but I'm confused about how to use them with datasets of different sizes.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def _interleave_data(filename):
    ds_part = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(_parse_features)
    ds_part = ds_part.map(_do_some_processing) 
    return ds_part

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filenames)
ds = dataset.interleave(_interleave_data)
```

Is there any elegant way to do it? Thanks!